# Chrome devtools shortcuts might not work in Windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know why are some Chrome devtools' shortcuts not working in Windows 10? I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open devtools, but when I want to inspect a node using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or toggle device toolbar using  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, it doesn't work.